# Rest API Call using PUT method

Tags: ios, swift

I am using below method to perform server call, when i am using httpmethod GET & POST its working fine but the problem is its not working when i am using PUT method with passing one parameter, its giving me response the passing parameter is required. please help me whats the problem..

```
func MakeRequestToServer(url: String, httpMethod:String, parameters: String, completionHandler: ((response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?)->())) {
    //

    var URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!

    var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)

    request.HTTPMethod = httpMethod


    var bodyData = parameters

    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response, data, error) -> Void in
        //
        completionHandler(response: response, data: data, error: error)
    }
}
```

this is my controller to calling this server function.

```
service.MakeRequestToServer(setting.bindURL(setting.acceptBookings), httpMethod: "PUT", parameters: parameters) {
        (response, data, error) in

        var d = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        println(d)
}
```

Comment: Is the error coming from your server? Some servers might not accept PUT requests, or might require a configuration change to accept PUT.

Comment: the same server api is used in android also and its working fine, but for me its returning error message because while sending in put , request parameter are not getting in server.

Comment: so is it server side issue or client

Comment: Sounds like client side then. What is the exact error message, and on what line of code does it occur?

Comment: i am getting the error message in response from server response, that server required the parameter but i am sending that parameter too, this problem i am getting only in PUT method

Comment: Your service is calling MakePutRequestToServer but you have only shown code for MakeRequestToServer.

Comment: oops my mistake i typed, actually

Comment: Please show your `parameters` variable.

Comment: var params = ""
        params += "start_lat=lat&"
        params += "start_long=long&"
        params += "starttime=time&"
        params += "status=Started"